# Replacing `<=?` with `CmpNat`

Tags: haskell, type-families

I've the following type family:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Kind
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Type.Bool

type family Valid (n :: Nat) :: Constraint where
  Valid (n :: Nat) = ( KnownNat n
                     , If (2 <=? n && n <=? 16)
                          (() :: Constraint)
                          (TypeError ('Text "No Good"))
                     )
```

This works as expected. But GHC has a [note](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:-60--61--63-) that `<=?` might go away in favor of `CmpNat`. My attempts at replacing the use of `<=?` with `CmpNat` has failed so far. This version, for instance:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Kind
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Type.Bool

type family Valid (n :: Nat) :: Constraint where
  Valid (n :: Nat) = ( KnownNat n
                     , If ((CmpNat 2 n ~ 'EQ || CmpNat 2 n ~ 'LT) && (CmpNat n 16 ~ 'EQ || CmpNat n 16 ~ 'LT))
                          (() :: Constraint)
                          (TypeError ('Text "No Good"))
                     )
```

is not only more verbose, GHC rightfully doesn't like it because the constituents of the type-level boolean and/or are no longer bools themselves:

```
    • Expected kind ‘Bool’,
        but ‘CmpNat 2 n ~ 'EQ’ has kind ‘Constraint’
    • In the first argument of ‘(||)’, namely ‘CmpNat 2 n ~ 'EQ’
      In the first argument of ‘(&&)’, namely
        ‘(CmpNat 2 n ~ 'EQ || CmpNat 2 n ~ 'LT)’
      In the first argument of ‘If’, namely
        ‘((CmpNat 2 n ~ 'EQ || CmpNat 2 n ~ 'LT)
          && (CmpNat n 16 ~ 'EQ || CmpNat n 16 ~ 'LT))’
   |
13 |                      , If ((CmpNat 2 n ~ 'EQ || CmpNat 2 n ~ 'LT) && (CmpNat n 16 ~ 'EQ || CmpNat n 16 ~ 'LT))
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Simplifying the constraints a bit, one can also write more concisely:

```hs
   CmpNat 1 n ~ 'LT && CmpNat n 17 ~ 'LT
```

but GHC still doesn't like that, giving the same type error for the very same reason as before.

What would be the cleanest way to use `CmpNat` instead of `<=?` in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CmpNat 2 n ~ 'EQ` is a *constraint*, not a boolean.

```
Prelude> :k 'EQ ~ 'EQ
'EQ ~ 'EQ :: Constraint
```

Basically, a constraint can only ever be proven, not disproven, and therefore can't be used in an `If` statement.

(It may seem silly that there's a sense of equality that “can never be false”, but actually there are good reasons for that kind of thing. Compare with booleans vs. *propositions* in Coq.)

What you want instead is `` CmpNat 2 n == 'EQ` ``.

```
Prelude Data.Type.Equality> :k 'EQ == 'EQ
'EQ == 'EQ :: Bool
```

Comment: That was exactly the missing piece! Thanks.